# How does Navigation Controller work with Split View Controller under the hood?

Tags: ios, iphone

I have difficulty understanding the behavior on iPhone(Portrait).

Several cases:

1. No navigation controller for both master and detail, it shows master in the beginning.
2. If master is embedded in a navigation controller, then it shows detail first, yet you can go back to master through navigation bar. **Question: Master is the only one embedded in navigation controller, isn't it supposed to be the only controller on navigation stack? How does detail get a navigation bar and pop-off effect like it is on that stack as well?**
3. If I go the other way around, put a navigation controller in Detail instead of Master. Not surprisingly, it shows Master first this time. Yet Master does not get the same treatment, it does not get a navigation bar, and there is no way you can go back from it to Detail. **Question: What causes this different "treatment"?**